# Complex Drupal setup using Views, Entity/Node Reference and custom content type

Tags: views, nodes, entities

OK, here is my setup, i will then explain what im trying to achieve:

I have a content type of DELIVERY another content type of BOOK and another content type of FEEDBACK

Now, any given user can have anywhere from 1 to 12 DELIVERY content types created (these are created using Rules automatically when they sign up). I use the Node Reference field to attach a BOOK to the DELIVERY content type, if the user has more than 1 delivery content, i will be attaching different books to each delivery content each month. When i attach a book to the users delivery, they can then create a FEEDBACK content to leave feedback under that particular DELIVERY.

So for example,

```
User 1 
  - Delivery 1 
       - Book 1 
       - Book 2 
  - Deliver 2 
       - Book 3
```

I want the user to be able to create a Feedback content and select the relevant book that the feedback belongs to and once saved it should appear under the particular delivery content.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Do you have a question?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add a node reference field on the **Feedback** content type. When your user creates a new **Feedback** node, they should be able to select the correct **Delivery** node to associate it with.

You will most likely want to constrain the user's selection options to **Delivery** nodes associated with that particular user so that User 1 doesn't leave feedback about User 2's delivery. One way to do this is to create a custom autocomplete function and use `hook_form_alter()` to edit the **Delivery** node reference field on the **Feedback** node create/edit form.

On a **Delivery** node, to display **Feedback** nodes that are associated with that **Delivery** node, you can create a View that has shows **Feedback** nodes that are associated with the currently logged in user and references the current node nid (use contextual filters for both).